# @Inputting data from a 'param' component; has not selector tag for property binding

Tags: angular, property-binding

So im in a bit of a pickle here.

I have an ArtistsComponent, which has a display of a bunch of music artists. When you click on an img, it routes to an ArtistPageComponent:

Also, here are the path for the components as well

```
{ path: 'artists', component: ArtistsComponent },

{ path: 'artists/:artistId', component: ArtistPageComponent },
```

**ARTISTS**

HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let x of artistData.artists'
      class="artist">
      <img
        src="{{ x.artistsPicture }}"
        [routerLink]="['/artists', 'artistId']"
        >
        <p>{{ x.artistName }}</p>
</div>
```

Component.Ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './../../data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'artists',
  templateUrl: './artists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artists.component.css']
})
export class ArtistsComponent {

  constructor(
      private dataService: DataService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  artistData = this.dataService.data;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route);
  }

}
```

Here is the ArtistPageComponent code:

**ARTISTPAGE**

HTML

```
<p>
  {{ artistId }}
</p>
```

Component.Ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from './../../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'artistpage',
  templateUrl: './artistpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artistpage.component.css']
})

export class ArtistPageComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input(): artist = '';

  artistId:string = '';
  artistData = this.dataService.data;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService
  ){  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.artistId = this.route.snapshot.params.artistId;
    console.log(this.route);
    console.log(this.artistData.artists)
  }
}
```

I dont really know how to property bind for the input without having a component selector. So i am thinking, once you click on an img, get the data associated with that artist and input it into the ArtistPageComponent. I just dont know how to execute it if that is the correct way of going about it.

For what it is worth, here is a portion of the data service.

```
"artists": [
      {
        "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/lupe.jpg",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "The Cool",
            "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/thecool.jpeg",
            "songs": [
              { "name": "Baba Says Cool for Thought",
                "track number" : "1",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Free Chilly ft Sarah Green and GemStones",
                "track number" : "2",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Go Go Gadget Flow",
                "track number" : "3",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "The Coolest",
                "track number" : "4",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Superstar ft Matthew Santos",
                "track number" : "5",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Paris, Tokyo",
                "track number" : "6",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Hi-Definition ft Snoop Dogg and Pooh Bear",
                "track number" : "7",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Gold Watch",
                "track number" : "8",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Hip-Hop Saved My Life ft Nikki Jean",
                "track number" : "9",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Intruder Alert ft Sarah Green",
                "track number" : "10",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Streets on Fire ft Matthew Santos",
                "track number" : "11",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Little Weapon ft Bishop G and Nikki Jean",
                "track number" : "12",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Gotta Eat",
                "track number" : "13",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Dumb It Down ft GemStones and Graham Burris",
                "track number" : "14",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Hello / Goodbye (Uncool) ft Unkle",
                "track number" : "15",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "The Die ft GemStones",
                "track number" : "16",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Put You on Game",
                "track number" : "17",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Fighters ft Matthew Santos",
                "track number" : "18",
                "file": "mp3" },
              { "name": "Go Baby ft GemStones",
                "track number" : "19",
                "file": "mp3" },
            ]
          },
          { "name": "Food & Liquor",
            "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/f&l.jpg",
            "songs": [
              { "name": "Intro",
                "track number" : "1",
                "file": "mp3"
              },
              { "name": "Real ft Sarah Green",
                "track number" : "2",
                "file": "mp3"
              },
              { "name": "Just Might Be O.K. ft Gemini",
                "track number" : "3",
                "file": "mp3"
              },...............
```

Comment: What does "I dont really know how to property bind for the input without having a component selector" mean? You pasted a lot of code but your actual question is unclear.

Comment: I believe when you input a property to another component, for the child component, you have to have a property binding in the selector. Example, <artistpagecomponent [property]="expression"></artistspagecomponent>    I dont see any way of doing that the way I have it set up. I dont really know how else to articulate what I am trying to ask

Comment: You don't do anything related to selectors for the child component, you just need to have an `@Input()` property in the child component.

Comment: I do have it in the child component, i just do not know what to do from that point forward

Comment: Parent component might have `<artistpagecomponent [property]="expression">` and then in the ArtistPageComponent you would have `@Input() property;`

Comment: There is not selector/element for artistpagecomponent anywhere in the html for artistcomponent. Thats what I am particularly confused about lol. I am probably missing something really obvious

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the link I sent to you in your last question here? I have an app that does 'movies' that is very similar to what you are doing here with artists. You should be able to copy much of that code (and rename 'movie' to 'artist'). :-) https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Comment: ahh i see. I wasnt able to run your app but im going to try again and really study it to see where i am going wrong. thank you very much !

Comment: finally got it to run! yes, it is very simlar to what i am trying to accomplish. I am going to build a clone of your app in my image to learn for myself. Thank you very much